What is wrong with the way I calculated this integral ? $\Omega = \int^{\infty}_{0}\left({1+\frac{1}{x(x+1)}-\text{coth}(x)}\right)\frac{dx}{x}$
What is wrong with the way I calculated this integral ?
$$\Omega =\int^{\infty}_{0}\left({1+\frac{1}{x(x+1)}-\text{coth}(x)}\right)\frac{dx}{x}$$
My solution:
$$I(n)=\int^n_0\left({1+\frac{1}{x(x+1)}-\text{coth}(x)}\right)\frac{dx}{x}=\int^n_0\left({\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{\text{coth}(x)}{x}}\right)dx$$
we have :
$$\frac{\coth(x)}{x}=\sum^{\infty}_{k=-\infty}\frac{1}{x^2+k^2\pi^2}=\frac{1}{x^2}+2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2+k^2\pi^2}$$
$$I_n=\int^n_0\left({\frac{1}{x+1}-2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2+k^2\pi^2}}\right)dx=\left[{\ln(x+1)-\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\tan^{-1}\left({\frac{x}{k\pi}}\right)}\right]_0^n$$
$$I_n=\ln(n+1)-\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\tan^{-1}\left({\frac{n}{k\pi}}\right)$$
Therefore:
\begin{align*}\Omega &=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left({\ln(n+1)-\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\tan^{-1}\left({\frac{n}{k\pi}}\right)}\right)\\&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left({\ln(n+1)-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}}\right)=-\gamma\end{align*}
But this answer is wrong because the correct answer is
$$\Omega =\ln(\pi)-\gamma$$
I can't understand where I went wrong. Where is the error in the solution ?

The first line, where you distribute the $1/x$ does not seem right.

That's right. I checked my calculations carefully.

After "Therefore:" I'm not sure if you are quite correct in changing
\begin{equation*}
-\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{n}{k\pi}\right)}
\end{equation*}
to the sum of $1/k$ from $k = 1$ to $n$ in the limit. I think you will find that the difference in going from the first sum to the second is the missing $\log(\pi)$.

$$I(n)=\int^n_0\left({1+\frac{1}{x(x+1)}-\text{coth}(x)}\right)\frac{dx}{x}=\int^n_0\left({\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2(x+1)}-\frac{\text{coth}(x)}{x}}\right)dx$$

(I agree with your initial simplification of the integral up to "Therefore.")

Let's start from
$$I_n=\ln(n+1)-\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\arctan\left(\frac{n}{k\pi}\right)=\ln(n+1)-\frac2\pi S(n)$$
where
$$S(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\arctan\left({\frac{n}{k\pi}}\right)+\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\arctan\left(\frac{n}{k\pi}\right)$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\left(\frac\pi2-\arctan\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)\right)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1n\frac{1}{1+\frac kn}\arctan\left(\frac1{\pi(\frac kn+1)}\right)$$
Leading $n\to\infty$
$$S(n)=\frac\pi2(\ln n+\gamma)-\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(\pi x)}xdx+\int_1^\infty\frac{\arctan\frac1{\pi t}}tdt+o(1)$$
$$=\frac\pi2(\ln n+\gamma)-\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(\pi x)}xdx+\int_0^1\frac{\arctan\frac x\pi}xdx+o(1)$$
$$=\frac\pi2(\ln n+\gamma)-\int_\frac1\pi^\pi\frac{\arctan x}xdx+o(1)$$
Making the substitution $x\to\frac1x$ and using again $\,\arctan\frac1x=\frac\pi2-\arctan x$
$$S(n)=\frac\pi2(\ln n+\gamma)-\frac\pi4\int_\frac1\pi^\pi\frac{dx}x+o(1)=\frac\pi2(\ln n+\gamma)-\frac\pi2\ln\pi+o(1)$$
$$I_n=\ln(n+1)-\frac2\pi S(n)=\ln\frac{n+1}n-\gamma+\ln\pi+o(1)\to\boxed{\ln\pi-\gamma\,}\,\,\,\text{at}\,\,n\to\infty$$
